# How to disable eslint in eslint-plugin-vue?

Tags: vue.js, eslint

Been trying to figure out this for quite some while now. Also wondering how to disable rules individually? I've tried various ways but it never really works.

Comment: if you installed vue with cli, you should have dedicated eslint file where you can edit rules.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

`/* eslint-disable-next-line */` to disable the linter for next line of your code

`/* eslint-disable-name-of-rule */` to disable only a specific rule

`/* eslint-disable */` at the top of a file to disable the linter for the current file

You can also create a .eslintrc.js file to configure the linter globally as specified here https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: Not in a Vue template.

Comment: yes not in the template.